# How to write complex string into Gson classes

Tags: java, json, gson

I've been racking my brain attempting to make pojos to consume the following json string. One thing I've been doing is making multiple pojos within pojos similar to what would be necessary inside of spring boot. Not sure if this is also needed for GSON. After numerous attempts I've still havent gotten it. Thanks for any advice in advance.

Json String:

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": "superficial",
            "language": "en",
            "lexicalEntries": [
                {
                    "derivatives": [
                        {
                            "id": "superficialness",
                            "text": "superficialness"
                        }
                    ],
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "etymologies": [
                                "late Middle English: from late Latin superficialis, from Latin superficies (see superficies)"
                            ],
                            "grammaticalFeatures": [
                                {
                                    "text": "Positive",
                                    "type": "Degree"
                                }
                            ],
                            "homographNumber": "000",
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "existing or occurring at or on the surface"
                                    ],
                                    "examples": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "the building suffered only superficial damage"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus1014360.017",
                                    "short_definitions": [
                                        "existing or occurring at or on surface"
                                    ],
                                    "subsenses": [
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "situated or occurring on the skin or immediately beneath it"
                                            ],
                                            "domains": [
                                                "Anatomy",
                                                "Medicine"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "the superficial muscle groups"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus1014360.019",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "situated or occurring on skin or immediately beneath it"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "appearing to be true or real only until examined more closely"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "the resemblance between the breeds is superficial"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus1014360.020",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "appearing to be true or real only until examined more closely"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "superficial",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0014419.004"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "not thorough, deep, or complete; cursory"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "he had only the most superficial knowledge of foreign countries"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus1014360.021",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "not thorough or complete"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "superficial",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0014419.003"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "definitions": [
                                                "not having or showing any depth of character or understanding"
                                            ],
                                            "examples": [
                                                {
                                                    "text": "perhaps I was a superficial person"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "id": "m_en_gbus1014360.022",
                                            "short_definitions": [
                                                "not having or showing any depth of character or understanding"
                                            ],
                                            "thesaurusLinks": [
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "superficial",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0014419.006"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "entry_id": "superficial",
                                                    "sense_id": "t_en_gb0014419.002"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "thesaurusLinks": [
                                        {
                                            "entry_id": "superficial",
                                            "sense_id": "t_en_gb0014419.001"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en",
                    "lexicalCategory": "Adjective",
                    "pronunciations": [
                        {
                            "dialects": [
                                "American English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "respell",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "ˌso͞opərˈfiSHəl"
                        },
                        {
                            "audioFile": "http://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/superficial_us_1.mp3",
                            "dialects": [
                                "American English"
                            ],
                            "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                            "phoneticSpelling": "ˌsupərˈfɪʃəl"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "superficial"
                }
            ],
            "type": "headword",
            "word": "superficial"
        }
```

Pojos:

```
class Results {

    private String id;
    private String language;
    private String lexicalEntries;
    private String type;
    private String word;

//
}

class Derivatives {

    private String id;
    private String text;
//
    }


class Entries {

    private String etymologies;
    private String grammaticalFeatures;
    private int homographNumber;
    private List<String> senses;
    //
}

public class LexicalEntries {

    private Derivatives derivatives;
    private List<Entries> entries;
    private String language;
    private String lexicalCategory;
    private List<Pronunciations> pronunciations;
    private String text;
//
}

public class Pronunciations {

    private String dialects;
    private String phoneticNotation;
    private String phoneticSpelling;
//
}

class Senses {

    private String definitions;
    private String examples;
    private String id;
    private ShortDefinitions short_definitions;
    private List<Subsenses> subsenses;
    private List<ThesaurusLinks> thesaurusLinks;
//

}

class ShortDefinitions {

    private String short_definitions;
//
}

class Subsenses {

    private String definitions;
    private String domains;
    private String examples;
    private String id;
    private String shortDefinitions;
    private String thesaurusLinks;
//
}

class ThesaurusLinks {
    private String entry_id;
    private String sense_id;
//
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with building the corresponding classes?

Comment: Hello, I've added my classes but i get back a null pointer. I'm assuming my classes are wrong. Note I have all setters and getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your POJO class definitions as per your JSON.

> I would recommend you reading JSON notation, how different data types are represented in it like Array/List, Object, String, int, boolean. It will clarify your understanding and you will know why your classes were not properly mapped to JSON data schema.

```
class Results {

    private String id;
    private String language;
    private List<LexicalEntry> lexicalEntries;
    private String type;
    private String word;

//
}

public class LexicalEntry {

    private List<Derivative> derivatives;
    private List<Entry> entries;
    private String language;
    private String lexicalCategory;
    private List<Pronunciation> pronunciations;
    private String text;
//
}

class Derivative {

    private String id;
    private String text;
//
}


class Entry {

    private List<String> etymologies;
    private List<GrammaticalFeature> grammaticalFeatures;
    private String homographNumber; //if it has quotes in JSON, it will be a string not int..JSON is a strongly typed object notation
    private List<Sense> senses;
    //
}

class GrammaticalFeature{
    String text;
    String type;
}



public class Pronunciation {
    private String audioFile;
    private List<String> dialects;
    private String phoneticNotation;
    private String phoneticSpelling;
//
}

class Sense {

    private List<String> definitions;
    private List<Example> examples;
    private String id;
    private List<String> short_definitions;
    private List<Subsense> subsenses;
    private List<ThesaurusLinks> thesaurusLinks;
//

}

class Example{
    String text;
}

class Subsense {

    private List<String> definitions;
    private List<String> domains;
    private List<Example> examples;
    private String id;
    private List<String> shortDefinitions;
    private List<ThesaurusLink> thesaurusLinks;
//
}

class ThesaurusLink {
    private String entry_id;
    private String sense_id;
//
}
```